# Ignore namespaces while unmarshalling : JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

When I'm trying to convert xml to Java Object using JAXB, which contains namespaces, error occurs.

Sample Example:
`

    Zeta
    Walnes

```
<dob>1991-11-12</dob>

<urn2:phone xmlns:urn1="urn:example:names:id:ubl:schema:xsd:Phone-2">
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-456</number>
</urn2:phone>
<fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
</fax>
```

`

I need to ignore the namespaces & convert into object.

Comment: what error occurs? Sample code?

Comment: Is it whole document? Where is the root element?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<urn:person xmlns:urn="urn:example:names:id:ubl:schema:xsd:Demo-2">
 <urn1:firstname xmlns:urn1="urn:example:names:id:ubl:schema:xsd:Name-2">Zeta</urn1:firstname>
 <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
 
 <dob>1991-11-12</dob>
 
 <urn2:phone xmlns:urn1="urn:example:names:id:ubl:schema:xsd:Name-2">
  <code>123</code>
  <number>9999-456</number>
 </urn2:phone>
 <fax>
  <code>123</code>
  <number>9999-999<number>
 </fax>
</urn:person>

Comment: It is an xml file with various namespaces included

Answer (score 0):

If You are using DocumentBuilderFactory to build your org.w3c.dom.Document, you can use:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
```

Also you can use a package-info.java file to set namespace